# Assign a random fraction to classes

Tags: r, random

I have

- 5 classes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`
- a range from 0-100%

I want that a random fraction of my range is assigned to each of the classes, e.g.

```
A | 10%
B | 20%
C | 17% 
D | 33%
E | 20%
=========
  | 100%
```

or

```
A | 29%
B | 1%
C | 23% 
D | 17%
E | 30%
=========
  | 100%
```

I couldn't come up with a straight-forward way to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want completely random values or values around a particular pre-specified percentages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do what you want.

```
set.seed(2394)    # Make the results reproducible

cl <- sample(0:100, 5, TRUE)
cl <- round(100*cl/sum(cl))
cl
#[1]  3 23 26 26 22

sum(cl)
#[1] 100
```

Comment: My initial post had `sample(100, etc)` but this samples [from `1:100` (see section Details)](http://127.0.0.1:13934/library/base/html/sample.html) and you explicitly say you want to sample from `0:100`. In this case it must be `sample(0:100, etc)`. Bug corrected.